# .htaccess redirect problem

Tags: apache

I am struggling with my htaccess. I have multiple redirects, some works some don't i can't figure out why
This works:

```
RewriteRule ^submit/*$ public/submit.php
RewriteRule ^articles/*$ public/articles.php
```

But this doesn't

```
RewriteRule ^books/*$ public/books.php
```

I have no idea why my code doesn't work, it gives me a 404 when i try to access

```
http://www.example.com/books/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that you have a folder called books, but not a folder called submit or articles. That might explain difference in behavior.

Comment: wow, i had a file called books.sql in the same folder. i copied it there temporarily and i forget to delete it. as soon as i removed it, my page is working now, Thank you so much i struggled for hours with this